# Морфолого-синтаксический способ словообразования

Tags: лексика, словообразование, существительные

Я непосредственно про субстантивацию.

Как известно, субстантивация — переход в разряд имён существительных слов, принадлежащих другим частям речи.
Примеры субстантивации таковы: в словосочетании *больной человек* слово "больной" как часть речи — прилагательное; в словосочетании *больной вышел* слово "больной" как часть речи — существительное.

Меня же интересует, каждое ли прилагательное (причастие, местоимение, числительное) переходит в состав существительных, когда одно из четырёх находится самостоятельно в предложении? То есть в предложении *Баловавшийся накликал беду* слово "баловавшийся" как часть речи не причастие, а существительное?
Или же переход прилагательного (причастия, местоимения, числительного) — процесс исторический и не каждое прилагательное (причастие, местоимение), употреблённое самостоятельно, переходит в состав существительных?

Answer (score 1):

Существительные, пережившие как **полную** (*лесничий, портной, прачечная*), так и **частичную** (*командующий, военный, раненый, первое-второе-третье, нищий, ничья, легавый*) субстантивацию, являются фактом языка и зафиксированы толковыми словарями.

Особый тип составляют ситуативные субстантивированные образования, т. е. те прилагательные и причастия (в этой же роли могут быть использованы местоимения и числительные), которые субстантивируются лишь **в данном контексте** (как ваш *баловавшийся*).

Вот классический пример (М. Булгаков. Собачье сердце):

> — А водка должна быть в сорок градусов, а не в тридцать, это во-первых, — наставительно перебил Филипп Филиппович, — а во-вторых, бог их знает, что они туда плеснули. Вы можете сказать, что им придет в голову?
> — Все, что угодно, — уверенно молвил **тяпнутый**.
> — И я того же мнения, — добавил Филипп Филиппович и вышвырнул одним комком содержимое рюмки себе в горло, — э... мм... доктор Борменталь, умоляю вас: мгновенно эту штучку, и если вы скажете, что это плохо, я ваш кровный враг на всю жизнь. «От Севильи до Гренады!..»
> С этими словами он подцепил на лапчатую серебряную вилку что-то похожее на маленький темный хлебик. **Укушенный** последовал его примеру. Глаза Филиппа Филипповича засветились.

Субстантивированные образования такого рода индивидуальны, носят временный характер, создаются лишь применительно к данной ситуации и в словарях, как правило, не фиксируются.

В ответе использованы материалы статьи ["Субстантивация в русском языке — переход прилагательных в существительные"](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/139.htm).
Интересна, мне кажется, и вот эта информация: ["Три плюс два (о субстантивации числительных в русском языке)"](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/tri-plyus-dva-o-substantivatsii-chislitelnyh-v-russkom-yazyke/viewer).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за обстоятельный, подробный ответ. Но я не получил ответа на вопрос, который меня больше всего волновал: мой "баловавшийся" как часть речи стал существительным?

Comment: Обычно пишут так:  причастие, употребленное в роли существительного, или субстантивированное причастие (т. е. перешедшее в разряд существительных). Получается, что в данном контексте (но только в данном!) это существительное.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо)